# Set of fixed points is convex proof

Tags: convex-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

i am stuck as to how the author jumps from the 2 inequalities to two equalities in the following theorem.

[image: Proof]

For context i state theorem 1.11:
Let X be a uniformly convex Banach space and $C \subset X$ which is nonvoid,closed,convex and bounded.If $f: C\rightarrow C$ is a non expansive map then f has a fixed point.

I understand how the inequalities are derived but not how these inequalities imply the equalities.

Presumably,i would like to show that $||f(x_t)-f(x_0)||<t||x_1-x_0||$ is false and so the equality has to occur.
Any hint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have
$$||x_1 - x_0|| = ||f(x_t) - x_0 + x_1 - f(x_t)||\leq ||f(x_t) - x_0|| + ||f(x_t) - x_1||$$
by triangle inequality. Hence
$$||x_1 - x_0|| \leq ||f(x_t) - x_0|| + ||f(x_t) - x_1||\leq $$
$$ \leq t||x_1 - x_0|| + (1-t)||x_1 - x_0|| = ||x_1 - x_0||$$
Thus we have $=$ everywhere instead of $\leq$.